# Install MonoDevelop with a custom Mono installation prefix

Tags: mono, makefile, monodevelop, automake

I have compiled mono from source and installed with `--prefix=/opt/mono-2.8.2`.

Now I want to install monodevelop with this current mono. I have seen `./configure --help` of monodevelop. But didn't find any switch where I can set the path of mono installation.

My question is how can I install monodevelop when mono is installed in `/opt/mono-2.8.2`

**Update 1:**

After checking some documentation of `./configure` command I think I have to change the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` global variable to a path so that it contains my custom mono installation directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anytime I build anything with mono I set PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

```
export PATH=/opt/mono-2.8.2/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mono-2.8.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono-2.8.2/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

./configure --prefix=/opt/mono-2.8.2
make
make install
```

Comment: It worked. In fact I tried with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono-2.8.2`. It didn't work because I didn't use `export`. Just an inch difference. Thanks a lot.